# Application.config "disappears" while debugging Azure WebRole if I pause at a breakpoint for too long

Tags: debugging, azure, visual-studio-2013, webrole

I've noticed this off and on. If I'm locally debugging my Azure WebRole, in Visual Studio 2013, and I pause at a break-point for too long, the current request, or the next one, and all subsequent requests, will result in a 500.19 - Internal Server Error.

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module          CustomErrorModule
Notification    SendResponse
Handler         Not yet determined
Error Code      0x80070490
Config Error    The configuration section 'system.webServer/httpErrors' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
Config File     \\?\C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\11468ba0-d99a-45d2-bcce-eae28c7b4e2f\temp\temp\RoleTemp\applicationHost.config
Requested URL   <request url>
Physical Path      
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User      Not yet determined
```

Event viewer says:

```
The worker process for application pool '902aa9af-0ed8-4126-be43-e533339bdeef' encountered an error 'Cannot read configuration file' trying to read global
module configuration data from file '\\?\C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\11468ba0-d99a-45d2-bcce-eae28c7b4e2f\temp\temp\RoleTemp\applicationHost.config', 
line number '0'.  Worker process startup aborted.
```

And if I go check that directory I see that the file isn't there. I'm guessing the file WAS there at some point, because I was able to make requests prior to that.

Restarting the WebRole seems to fix the problem.

99% of the time this isn't a problem, so I'm sure there isn't actually an error in the config file, it just makes debugging "stressful" since I always feel like I'm under some kind of time limit. :(

Comment: Kinda disappointed no-one has any thoughts on this. It happens to me repeatedly, and now it's happening in VS 2015 with Azure 2.7

Comment: Solution mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665443/application-config-disappears-while-debugging-azure-webrole-if-i-pause-at-a-br) worked for me.

Comment: That just seems to point back to this question?

Comment: Correct Link - http://www.thedailyparker.com/PermaLink,guid,aa5142ff-846a-4764-9a22-a390c79a2578.aspx

Comment: Also running the role in full mode (instead of express mode) also solves the problem